# How the key-value databases work?

Tags: database, algorithm, data-structures, nosql, key-value

Does anyone know of any good articles or books or tutorials that explain how databases of this type work internally? I'm interested in algorithms, data structures.

Comment: Sadly these types of open-ended questions are not allowed on StackOverflow. They are encouraged on some other question-answer sites though.

Comment: Typically a consistent hash takes a key onto one storage bucket in a ring.  Writes block until a configured number (`W`) of machines acknowledge to increase durability.  Reads block until `R` machines agree on the value to return for increased consistency.  Go read http://www.allthingsdistributed.com/2007/10/amazons_dynamo.html

Answer (score 3):

[Redis](http://redis.io/) is one of such databases. Look at great answer of redis author here:

[What are the underlying data structures used for Redis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9625246/what-are-the-underlying-data-structures-used-for-redis)