# Redis get range from a Set?

Tags: nosql, redis

In Redis is it possible to get a range of items from a Set?

I only notice SMEMBERS which gives you all the members. http://redis.io/commands#set

For example, if I have to use SMEMBERS in millions of items everytime, I just want 10 of them from index 33,456 to 33,466.

SMEMBERS will have to generate a full list of millions of items everytime I ask for 10 of them. Isn't that a performance killer? Or is it okay because Redis is fast and meant to be used that way?

Comment: A set is a non ordered data structure. Fetching items by range in a set is meaningless. There is no concept of index. Perhaps you should use a list or a sorted set?

Comment: FYI: as of [Redis 2.6.0-RC8](http://antirez.com/post/redis-2.6-rc8-out.html) there is now a `SRANDMEMBER <count>` command that *returns multiple random elements* that you may find useful.

Comment: You might achieve your goal using the relatively feature-rich _sort_ command: http://redis.io/commands/sort

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot get `range` in set because it is **unordered**, hence no indexing. You can however get all members of the set using [SMEMBERS](https://redis.io/commands/smembers)

In redis-cli

```
SMEMBERS my_set
```

Also, [ZRange](http://redis.io/commands/zrange) might help you using [Sorted Sets](http://redis.io/commands#sorted_set) in redis

In redis-cli

```
ZRANGE your_key 33455 33465
```

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible, because the concept of an index does not exist in the Set data type. In fact, `SMEMBERS` does not guarantee you a specific order; most likely the order of the elements will be random every time you call it. Think of Sets as unordered collections of things: great if you need to store a bunch of ids that share something in common, but definitively not the data type to use if you need to implement pagination. Perhaps you are looking for [Lists](http://redis.io/commands#list) or [Sorted Sets](http://redis.io/commands#sorted_set) instead?

I recommend reading the following to understand the available data types in redis and when to use each:

- [Data types documentation](http://redis.io/topics/data-types)
- [What are the underlying data structures used for Redis?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9625246/1329367)