# in_array vs isset - performance

Tags: php, arrays

Consider following snippets of code:

**Example #1**

```
$array = Array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
$array_test = Array(3,5,4,7,3,6,7,8,8,9,3);

foreach($array_test as $value) {
   if(in_array($value, $array)) {
       // do some magic here
   }
}
```

**Example #2**

```
$array = Array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
$array_test = Array(3,5,4,7,3,6,7,8,8,9,3);

$array_index = Array();
foreach($array as $value) {
    $array_index[ $value ] = true;
}

foreach($array_test as $value) {
   if(isset($array_index[ $value ])) {
       // do some magic here
   }
}
```

Obviously both snippets do the same jobs. In some array samples example #1 is faster than example #2.

I am sure we all were in both situations, however my question is:

- Should I always choose #2?
- When should I choose #1? When size of `$array * $array_test` is < 10? <100? <1000?
- How to determine which method is better in particular situation?
- Maybe there is some other trick than using temp table `$array_index`. I don't remember similar situation in other programming languages, everything was ready as-you-go

Please mind about associative keys too.

Someone already asked very similar question:

- [what is faster: in_array or isset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13483219/what-is-faster-in-array-or-isset)

Comment: `in_array` has to use a linear time search to find your value. Looking for a key, though, is a constant time operation since PHP arrays are hash tables. So `in_array` should be the slowest. (If you have to write all your elements to a temporary array each time, though, it might not exactly be any faster.)

Comment: maybe try [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)?

Comment: array_diff and array_interesct doesn't fit here, consider common siutation where `$array_test` is just array of rows from db

Comment: I see. `array_intersect` would most likely be slower as well. `isset` should be much faster as @zneak commented.

Answer (score 4):

In your second example, you have to construct the "flipped" value of `$array` before you can use `isset()`. Btw, you can also use [`array_flip()`](http://www.php.net/array_flip) for that.

If you can use array keys immediately (without conversion), use `isset()` because it's obviously much faster than `in_array()` due to way keys are looked up *and* because it's a language construct.

If you can't use the keys without conversion, you could consider using `in_array()` for small arrays. For bigger arrays it might be worthwhile to run a benchmark to determine whether an array conversion step would still be worth it.

Lastly, and depending largely on the situation, you could use one of the `array_intersect_` functions as well, mainly to avoid having to loop inside PHP code.

Comment: i'll do some benchmarks tomorrow. `array_intersect` doesn't fit here as the most common situation is (for example) when I compare array of emails to array of rows from database

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski I think that should be mentioned in your question as well :)

Answer (score 1):

isset will always be faster than in_array because keys are unique and values are not. The fact that keys are unique give optimization possibilities that are impossible with values.