# PHP: Build a URL encoded while a value exists in multi array

Tags: php, arrays, array-walk

My goal is:

If a value in those arrays match with an extention of a file, then I can builds a nice URL encoded string which I can append to a url using the `http_build_query()` function. If no match is found, it return nothing.

I have tried it every possible way and it doesn't work, as the code below. can you check on which part is wrong ?.

```
$name = 'myfile.mp4';

$list = array(
     'video' => array('3gp', 'mkv', 'mp4'),
     'photo' => array('jpg', 'png', 'tiff')
);

// File Ext Check
$ext = (strpos($name, '.') !== false) ? strtolower(substr(strrchr($name, '.'), 1)) : '';

$type = null;
$find = $ext;

array_walk($list, function ($k, $v) use ($find, &$type) 
{
  if (in_array($find, $k))
  { 
    $type = $v;
    $data = array();

    switch ($type) 
    {
      case 'video':
         $data['title'] = 'video';
         $data['description'] = 'my video';
         break;
      case 'photo':
        $data['title'] = 'photo';
        $data['description'] = 'my photo';
        break;
    }
  }
  else {
    echo "not both!.";
    exit;
  {
});


if ($type == 'video') {
  $link = 'https://www.video.com' . http_build_query($data);
} 
else 
if ($type == 'photo') {
  $link = 'https://www.photo.com' . http_build_query($data);
}

echo $link;
```

Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `$data` is set in the `array_walk()` scope, but out of the `array_walk()` scope is not defined. So in the `http_build_query($data)`, here `$data` has not defined.

You may referende the `$data` in the `use()`, then after the `array_walk()`, you can use its value. In your code you use `in_array()` to check the file type in a list, for performance I recomend you to see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38602921/where-to-put-arrays-with-constant-value-that-will-be-accessed-many-times).

Comment: Hi there, all method on your recommended link is works. Thank you. BUT, I still can't figure out how to make the `array_walk()` works in my condition above. I want to understand and explore it. Can you gimme an exact answer?.

Comment: initial the $data out of array_walk(), then call array_walk($list, function ($k, $v) use ($find, &$type, &$data) );