# How to store an array with Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I have an array that I need in my Controller:

```
$myArray = array('key'=>'value', key1'=>'value1', 
                  key'=>'value', key'=>'value'key'=>'value'....);
```

It's not good to keep it like this.

Do you know where can I "store" and call it when its needed?

Comment: why is it not good to keep it like that ? what are you doing with this array ?

Comment: refer to this post http://stackoverflow.com/q/38602921/6521116

Comment: What's issue with this method?

Comment: I think it's a bad practice because I have more 25 items...

Comment: I think it's a bad practice because I have more 25 items... With this array I access to my entity and show it nicely. for exemple I have an entity and I want to convert the column name. For example: entity.champ will become myArray[entity.name]

Comment: Did you know that since this is an associate array, you can't have duplicate key values. For example, you can't use `'key1' => 'value', 'key1' => 'value2'`. The reason being if you try to access `$myArray['key1']` it wouldn't know which key to access.

Comment: I would suggest to put that array in a yml file and parse that file in your controller

Answer (score 0):

You can store the array in YAML file. Put the array into *Resources/config/my_array.yml* (or another file name) as follows:

```
key: "value"
key1: "value1"
...
```

In a controller you can get the array like this:

```
$locator = new \Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator($this->getParameter('kernel.root_dir') . '/../src/AppBundle/Resources/config');
$parser = new \Symfony\Component\Yaml\Parser();
$myArray = $parser->parse(file_get_contents($locator->locate('my_array.yml'));
```