# PHP array performance checking key existence vs checking values existence

Tags: php, arrays, performance, big-o

Is there a difference in O(n) of the below operations?

```
$a1 = [1=>'',2=>'', 3=>'']
isset($a1[2])

$a2 = [1,2, 3]
in_array(2, $a2)
```

Comment: [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) for values... sooo... they're not really meant for the same thing.

Comment: this is my guess... `isset` is faster because `in_array()` must look at the values.  `isset` just wants to know if that index exists regardless of what it actually holds.

Comment: possible duplicate of [what is faster: in\_array or isset?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13483219/what-is-faster-in-array-or-isset)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isset($a1[2])` has complexity of O(1)
`in_array(2, $a2)` has complexity of O(3) in your case or in general O(N) where N=count_of_the_array elements