# I wanted to allow only 1 comma between 2 letters in PHP validation

Tags: php, regex, validation

Hello I have a scenario that, in textbox I can enter string like

```
"1,2,3" this would be allowed.
```

but if someone enters,

```
"1,2,,3" this would not be allowed.
```

allowed multiple commas but not like above.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Try this reg-ex:

```
/^\d(?:,\d)*$/
```

Explanation:

```
/            # delimiter
  ^          # match the beginning of the string
  \d         # match a digit
    (?:      # open a non-capturing group
      ,      # match a comma
      \d     # match a digit
    )        # close the group
    *        # match the previous group zero or more times
  $          # match the end of the string
/            # delimiter
```

If you allow multi-digit numbers, then change \d to \d+.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
if(in_array("", explode(',',$str)))
{
    // validation fail
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is it's a bit overkill. You're splitting the string just to see if you have an empty spot. It works, but it's using a sledgehammer to drive a nail.

Comment: Yes, i agree with you, but OP is validating this for a checkbox, IMO we dont need to worry until OP has 10000 visitors at a given time, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13483548/3113793) answer, it says it took `1.738441 seconds` to perform 10000 iterations, we need only one here, so performance should not be considered here. Guide me if im wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do a regex test to check. If the only thing you want to prevent is duplicate commas:

```
if (preg_match('/,,/', $myString)) {
    // not allowed... do something about it
}
```

If you want to limit it to only a pattern of numbers, separated by commas, swap the regex pattern for `'/^([0-9]+,?)+$/'`, which only 1 or more numbers, optionally followed by a decimal, with that pattern repeated any number of times (but must have at least one number). Also, flip the conditional around, so:

```
if (!preg_match('/^([0-9]+,?)+$/', $myString)) {
    // not allowed... do something about it
}
```

If you want something a little simpler, doing this will also solve it (and be a little more efficient, if all you want is to test for multiple commas together):

```
if (strpos($myString, ',,') !== false) {
    // not allowed... do something about it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
if (strpos($input_string,',,') == true) {
    echo 'Invalid string';
}
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, a string of ",," would not be detected as invalid. Whether that's a use-case that the OP is considering or not is questionable, but it'd miss that since the index would be 0, which is not true.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect this using (preg_match will work too of course):

```
if(strpos($your_string, ',,') !== false) {
   echo "Invalid"
}
```

Do you also need to detect leading or trailing commas?
Also keep in mind if validation is not really necessary you can simply "fix" the input by using `explode` and filtering out empty string elements, and then `implode` array:

```
$your_string = implode(',', array_filter(explode(',', $your_string), function ($i) {
    return $i !== '';
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

use the `strpos()` function for your above requirement

```
 if (strpos($youstring,',,') == false) {
        echo 'String not found';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'String is found';
    }
```

Comment: What has this got to do with styling links?

Answer (score 0):

You can use stristr function to fix this

```
if(stristr ($Array,',,'))
echo 'Flase';
else
// do something
```