# Appending elements to array and skipping if some value exists[PHP]

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting

So, I'm trying to display an associative array generated from a table in my database. These are the steps I'm trying to accomplish:

1. Get result set from database that's already sorted in certain order based on a column(Ascending/Descending).
2. Add/Transfer/Append each record/row in the result set to another array. **While in the process** of appending, check if the array we are adding records has a value(based on a different column) similar to the record we are currently adding.
3. If the value we are checking for is already there, skip appending. If not, append the record and continue with the loop until the end of the result set.

This is the sample data I am working with, *tbl_user_details*:
[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8V4Z.png)

As you can see, it has been sorted in descending order based on the *user_pos* column. If you look at the *user_id* column, we have duplicate values. What I am trying to achieve is adding each record to an array and skipping the duplicate values based on the *user_id* column.user_id = 4 and *user_pos = 7*. Next will be ada with *user_id = 2* and *user_pos = 6*. The next record which we are not going add is woz with *user_id = 2* and *user_pos = 5* because we already have someone with *user_id = 2*. So, we skip to adding ghopper who has *user_id = 3* and *user_pos = 4*... and so forth. I think this example explains the flow of data I need displayed.

I've tried some simple code to get this done which it's clearly not working. Here is the snippet:

```
$query3 = "SELECT * FROM `user_details` ORDER BY `user_details`.`user_pos` DESC";

$user_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query3);

  if (!$user_set) {
    die("Database query failed.".mysqli_error($connection));
  }

  $user_arr = array();

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($user_set)) {

if (in_array($row["user_id"], $user_arr)) {
  continue; // skip if we already have this value in array
}

  $user_arr[] = $row;


}
```

The records that should be displayed are of aswartz, ada, ghopper and rasmusl. The rest are ignored. When I display the data in '$user_arr[]' using the foreach loop method, it still displays the whole data as it is on the table.

Comment: Can you add the dump of `$row` and `$user_arr` just to see the structure of the two arrays ?

Answer (score 1):

It will become multi dimensional array when you add `row` to `array` so you cant check `user_id` in it. There are many other solutions to check unique record but One simplest solution is to assign user_id as key then check key for duplication

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($user_set)) {

if (isset($user_arr[$row["user_id"]])) {
  continue; // skip if we already have this value in array
}

  $user_arr[$row["user_id"]] = $row;


}
```

**Note:** **If you want unique records only then you can use `DISTINCT` in query**

Comment: I just found your answer as easy to understand and more [faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13483219/what-is-faster-in-array-or-isset) Thanks for this answer I also leaned a lot.

Comment: This worked!! With regards to using `DISTINCT`, how can one tell which record was picked? I also tried `GROUP BY` but the sorting part was not how I wanted it to be.

Comment: @kipchirchirian if answer wored then accept.upvote answers. also to get help in  query you need to show your data and expected output

Comment: @B.Desai I upvoted but with my rep it doesn't have any effect. The data given in my question above should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Use another `$tempArr` which will contain only `user_id` to in `in_array`, In you code you are checking `user_id` against array or whole row which is user details not just against `user_ids`

```
$user_arr = array();
$tempArr = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($user_set)) {
    if (in_array($row["user_id"], $tempArr)) {
        continue; // skip if we already have this value in array
    }
    $user_arr[] = $row;
    $tempArr[] = $row["user_id"];
}
```