# Convert array to conditional php

Tags: php, arrays

I have and array, and I want to convert it into an if conditional.

```
$array = ['check 1', 'check 2', 'check 3'];
```

I want the final result to work like this:

```
if ($var == 'check 1' || $var == 'check 2' || $var == 'check 3') {
    // Do here.
}
```

I don't have any inspiration, I already searched for `convert array to if condition` but I couldn't find anything.

How can I convert the array into an if conditional?

Comment: `in_array` can be useful to you

Comment: but, how to check multiple value if i use `in_array`

Comment: Loop array. Check value of current iteration of the loop.

Comment: `if (in_array($var, $array) || in_array($var1, $array)){
//do something
}`

Comment: Where is the [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)? I cannot see any [array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php) in the code you posted.

Comment: @axiac `$array = ( 'check 1', 'check 2', 'check 3' );` ? then the code below is just an example wit normal var, but he wud like to achieve same using an array

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile `$array` in this code is not an [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). The code doesn't even compile, it reports a parsing error at the first comma. So, I'm asking again, where is the [array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php)?

Comment: A relevant/inspirational reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13483219/what-is-faster-in-array-or-isset

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of multiple `||` (OR) conditions use [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

```
if (in_array($var, $array)) {
    // do here
}
```

Output:-https://eval.in/914346

If you want to check multiple variables against array then do like this:-

```
if (in_array($var, $array) || in_array($var1, $array)){ 
  //do here
}
```

Output:- https://eval.in/914351

***Note:-*** If you can clarify more about all your variables and what conditions you want for all those variables, you will get more accurate answer

Answer (score 1):

Loop through array and check `in_array` like this:

```
$array = ( 'check 1', 'check 2', 'check 3' );

    foreach($array as $k => $v)
    {
        $flag = "false";
        if(in_array($v,$array))
        {
            $flag = "true";
        }
    }
```

So from above code, is any of the value exist in array, the variable $flag will have string value "`true`".

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$array = array( "mango", "grapes","apple");
//let you have to find apple

if(in_array('masngo',$array) || in_array('mango',$array)){
    echo "FIND";
    //OR WHATEVER YOU WANT TO DO
}else{
    echo "Not Found";
}
```

Try to run [HERE](http://phptester.net/)

Comment: This won't be a generic solution.