# Filter just duplicate urls from an php array

Tags: php, arrays, url, duplicates, filtering

Here is an array

```
Array ( 
   [EM Debt] => http://globalevolution.gws.fcnws.com/fs_Overview.html?isin=LU0616502026&culture=en-GB 
   [EM Local Debt] => Will be launched shortly 
   [EM Blended Debt] => Will be launched shortly 
   [Frontier Markets] => http://globalevolution.gws.fcnws.com/fs_Overview.html?isin=LU0501220262 
   [Absolute Return Debt and FX] => Will be launched shortly 
   [Em Debt] => http://globalevolution.gws.fcnws.com/fs_Overview.html?isin=LU0501220262 
)
```

If I use `array_unique()` it will filter `Will be launched shortly` from the array also.

I just want to filter duplicate urls, not text.

UPDATE:

**I need to be Array order remain as same, Just filter dupl**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you can use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

```
$filtered = array_filter($urls, function ($url) {
    static $used = [];

    if (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
        return isset($used[$url]) ? false : $used[$url] = true;
    }

    return true;
});
```

Here is [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2aac424ed09ba5f466c6502dbc3da4e768da6b79).

Comment: + for your filter_var and comments.

Comment: congrats.  you might want to add an explanation to your answer for completeness.

Answer (score 5):

Here is your answer:

```
<?php
// taking just example here, replace `$array` with yours
$array = ['http://globalevolution.gws.fcnws.com/fs_Overview.html?isin=LU0616502026&culture=en-GB', 'abc', 'abc', 'http://globalevolution.gws.fcnws.com/fs_Overview.html?isin=LU0616502026&culture=en-GB'];
$url_array = [];
foreach($array as $ele) {
    if(strpos($ele, 'http://') !== false) {
        $url_array[] = $ele;
    } else {
        $string_array[] = $ele;
    }
}

$url_array = array_unique($url_array);
print_r(array_merge($string_array, $url_array));
?>
```

Comment: Can we remain the order of array just filter duplicate urls ?

Comment: Because wen we merge again the order of array goes disturbed

Answer (score 5):

You can traverse the array one time to get the result, in this process you need to use an extra array to indicate which url you have saved in the result.

```
$saved_urls = [];
$result = [];
foreach($array as $k => $v)
{
    if('http://' == substr(trim($v), 0, 7) || 'https://' == substr(trim($v), 0, 8))
    {
        if(!isset($saved_urls[$v]))    // check if the url have saved
        {
            $result[$k] = $v;
            $saved_urls[$v] = 1;
        }
    }else
        $result[$k] = $v;
}
```

Comment: What if the link uses https?

Comment: @sevavietl You're right. I missed the `https` case.

Answer (score 3):

Okay here is I got the answer

```
$urls = ( [EM Debt] => http://globalevolution.gws.fcnws.com/fs_Overview.html?isin=LU0616502026&culture=en-GB 
[EM Local Debt] => Will be launched shortly 
[EM Blended Debt] => Will be launched shortly 
[Frontier Markets] => http://globalevolution.gws.fcnws.com/fs_Overview.html?isin=LU0501220262 [Absolute Return Debt and FX] => Will be launched shortly [Em Debt] => http://globalevolution.gws.fcnws.com/fs_Overview.html?isin=LU0501220262 );

$url_array = [];
foreach($urls as $title => $url) {
    if(strpos($url, 'http://') !== false) {
        $url_array[$title] = $url;
    } else {
        $string_array[$title] = $url;
    }
    $keys[] = $title;
}

$url_array = array_unique($url_array);
$urls = array_merge($url_array, $string_array);
$urls = array_sub_sort($urls, $keys);
```

Here is array sub sort function code.

```
function array_sub_sort(array $values, array $keys){
    $keys = array_flip($keys);
    return array_merge(array_intersect_key($keys, $values), array_intersect_key($values, $keys));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to modify the input array, not generate a new filtered array, you can use `strpos()` to identify urls, a `lookup` array to identify duplicate urls, and `unset()` to modify the array.

- `strpos($v,'http')===0` not only requires `http` to be in the string, it requires it to be the first four characters in the string.  To be clear, this accommodates `https` as well.  `strstr()` and `substr()` will always be less efficient than `strpos()` when simply checking the existence or position of a substring.  (The second note @ [PHP Manual's strstr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) boasts of the benefits of using `strpos()` when merely checking the existence of a substring.)
- Using iterated `in_array()` calls to check the `$lookup` array, is less efficient than storing the duplicate urls as keys in the lookup array.  `isset()` will outperform `in_array()` every time. ([Reference Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13483219/what-is-faster-in-array-or-isset))
- The OP's sample input does not indicate that there are any monkey-wrenching values that will start with `http` yet not be a url, nor non-urls that start with `http`.  For this reason, `strpos()` is a suitable and lightweight function call.  If trouble-making urls are possible, then sevavietl's url validation is a more reliable function call.  ([PHP Manual Link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php))
- From my online performance tests, my answer is the fastest method posted which provides the desired output array.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/52c1fc0cd32d2052bbed686a865f04b5abafe3aa))

```
$array=[
    'EM Debt'=>'http://globalevolution.gws.fcnws.com/fs_Overview.html?isin=LU0616502026&culture=en-GB',
    'EM Local Debt'=>'Will be launched shortly',
    'EM Blended Debt'=>'Will be launched shortly',
    'Frontier Markets'=>'http://globalevolution.gws.fcnws.com/fs_Overview.html?isin=LU0501220262',
    'Absolute Return Debt and FX'=>'Will be launched shortly',
    'Em Debt'=>'http://globalevolution.gws.fcnws.com/fs_Overview.html?isin=LU0501220262'
];

foreach($array as $k=>$v){
    if(isset($lookup[$v])){          // $v is a duplicate
        unset($array[$k]);           // remove it from $array
    }elseif(strpos($v,'http')===0){  // $v is a url (because starts with http or https)
        $lookup[$v]='';              // store $v in $lookup as a key to an empty string
    }
}
var_export($array);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'EM Debt' => 'http://globalevolution.gws.fcnws.com/fs_Overview.html?isin=LU0616502026&culture=en-GB',
  'EM Local Debt' => 'Will be launched shortly',
  'EM Blended Debt' => 'Will be launched shortly',
  'Frontier Markets' => 'http://globalevolution.gws.fcnws.com/fs_Overview.html?isin=LU0501220262',
  'Absolute Return Debt and FX' => 'Will be launched shortly',
)
```

---

Just for fun, a functional/unorthodox/convoluted method can look like this (not recommended, purely a demonstration):

```
var_export(
    array_intersect_key(
        $array,                                    // use $array to preserve order
        array_merge(                               // combine filtered urls and unfiltered non-urls
            array_unique(                          // remove duplicates
                array_filter($array,function($v){  // generate array of urls
                    return strpos($v,'http')===0;
                })
            ),
            array_filter($array,function($v){  // generate array of non-urls
                return strpos($v,'http')!==0;
            })
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: According to your predicate (`strpos($v,'http')===0`) "http is the best protocol in the world" considered an URL.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I complimented your method.  I'm not sure what you are trying to do to me.

Comment: thank you for the compliment. I though the purpose of this site is to discuss solutions in order to find the best (including pointing the pitfalls). Sorry if my comment offends you in any way.