# how to remove an array from multi dimensional array if include specific item in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Before:

```
$cars = array
  (
  array("Volvo",22,18),
  array("BMW",15,13),
  array("Saab",5,2),
  array("Land Rover",17,15)
  );
```

i want remove whole array witch include "**BMW**" as an item

result like this:

```
$cars = array
  (
  array("Volvo",22,18),
  array("Saab",5,2),
  array("Land Rover",17,15)
  );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to remove elements from an array based on custom logic. The callback function should return `true` or `false` if the element should be kept or removed respectively.

```
$filter = 'BMW';

$cars = array_filter($cars, function($car) use ($filter) {
    return $car[0] !== $filter;
});
```

Here, we're filtering out all rows where the first element is equal to the `$filter` variable.

See https://eval.in/950579

Comment: Will not work if array is like `[15,13,"BMW"],`, [check your demo](https://eval.in/950615)

Comment: @user2486, yeah, in that case, `in_array()` comes handy.....  https://stackoverflow.com/a/48641534/5527461

Comment: I was working against the examples given in the question, but I appreciate that the wording doesn't match that. Ataur Rahman's answer works best if the arrays can be in any order.

Comment: yes just wanted to mention that, `isset` is more faster than `in_array`

Comment: How does `isset` help when searching an array?

Comment: Thank you @iainn . your answer is most safest to me

Answer (score 3):

Just to extend @iainn answer

'BMW' may not always be the first element, so... [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

```
$filter = 'BMW';

$filteredCars = array_filter($cars, function($car) use($filter){
                       return in_array($filter, $car) === false;
                });
```

Comment: Good , `in_array` would work, just wanted to mention that, `isset` is more faster than `in_array`.

Comment: What's the benefit of 'faster' if there's a possibility of not working ?

Comment: yes definitely, but here isset will also work. see my answer

Comment: I am not saying your answer is wrong. even I upvoted your answer. Just wanted to mention about [this concept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13483219/what-is-faster-in-array-or-isset)

Answer (score 1):

I did this little function, keep in mind that the car-make has to be key [0].

**Example**

```
<?php
$cars = array
(
    array("Volvo", 22, 18),
    array("BMW", 15, 13),
    array("Saab", 5, 2),
    array("Land Rover", 17, 15)
);

function removeCar (array $cars, string $name): array
{
    $returnArray = array();
    foreach ($cars as $array => $car) {
        if ($car[0] != $name) {
            $returnArray[] = $car;
        }
    }
    return $returnArray;
}

$cars = removeCar($cars, "BMW");
print_r($cars);
```

**Output**

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Volvo [1] => 22 [2] => 18 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Saab [1] => 5 [2] => 2 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => Land Rover [1] => 17 [2] => 15 ) )
```

Hope this helps. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
<?php

$cars = array
(
array("Volvo",22,18),
array("BMW",15,13),
array("Saab",5,2),
array("Land Rover",17,15)
);

function removeFromArray($array, $make){
    $i = 0;
    $out = array();
    foreach ($array as $element) {
        if($element[0] != $make){
            $out[$i] = $element;
            $i++;
        }
    }
    return $out;
}
$cars = removeFromArray($cars, "BMW");
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`array_intersect_key`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) and [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php):

```
// Exclude one car.
$exclude = 'BMW';
$result = array_intersect_key($cars, array_filter(
    array_column($cars, 0),
    function ($car) use ($exclude) {
        return $car !== $exclude;
    }
));

var_dump($result);

// Exclude multiple cars.
$exclude = ['BMW', 'Saab'];
$result = array_intersect_key($cars, array_diff(array_column($cars, 0), $exclude));

var_dump($result);
```

Here is [the demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ac050a0bf26f4ad89b8f74340c65355eb76c9fcd).

Answer (score 0):

You can check each array using [foreach()](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop.

```
   $cars = array
      (
      array("Volvo",22,18),
      array("BMW",15,13),
      array("Saab",5,2),
      array("Land Rover",17,15)
      );


    $cars_filtered = array();  
    foreach($cars as $single){
        if($single[0]!='BMW'){
            $cars_filtered[] = $single;
        }   
    }

    print_r($cars_filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

To exclude item exist in array. You can do it by [`array_flip`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) and [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

```
foreach($cars as $key=>$value)  {
  if(isset(array_flip($value)["BMW"])){
    unset($cars[$key]);
  }
}
```

Live demo : https://eval.in/950611

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Volvo
            [1] => 22
            [2] => 18
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Saab
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Land Rover
            [1] => 17
            [2] => 15
        )

)
```

Comment: I am not much of a picky person.. but calling `array_flip` in `foreach` ??? seriously? What if the array consists of thousand elements?

Comment: @AtaurRahman : then even it is more faster : [check this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php#106895)

Comment: @AtaurRahman : Also check for this, [isset vs in_array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13483219/what-is-faster-in-array-or-isset)

Comment: Bro, You don't have to prove `fastness` of those function to me. I never said in_array is faster. But there is always some `situation based implementation`

Comment: ok great, but we can control the situation, we are programmers.

Comment: Okay. Then please do some benchmark rather than referencing five years old posts.... Create an array of 1000 elements (each on is an array of more 10 element)similar to OP's example and then benchmark how both of our codes perform. I don't want to be an arrogant nerd, but you should check out your own code first (Like I did).

Comment: @AtaurRahman : Both works as same , I didn't find any difference.Thanks

Comment: @AtaurRahman: I never wanted to share something like this but yeah it matters : https://eval.in/950765, but yes it `situation based implementation`

Comment: LOL... It isn't about the cycle of loop, its about size and content of the array... Let me know what will be the result and memory footprint of the array if I flip `array('id => 1, description => 'blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahbl')`

Comment: And You manipulated the benchmark as you stored flipped array in a variable outside of loop while did opposite to `in_array()`, I lost my interest in this topic. I won't reply anymore. Good Bye.