# Optimizing big string arrays for checking if a string exists queries

Tags: php

I have a big array that contains string values as the data. I want to optimize this array, so I can perform queries that check if a certain string exists in the array as quickly as possible. So let's say I create the array with `$arr= [];` and then add values like this:

```
foreach($names as $name)
    $arr[]= $name;
```

And now I want to perform a lot of queries like `if(in_array($random_string, $arr))`, but it's pretty slow. I'd like to add some indexing for the array to optimize the performance. Should I simply use the `sort()` function for the array?

How to optimize an array with string data for checking if a string exists queries?

*EDIT: No, obviously this is not a duplicate of "what is faster: in_array or isset? [closed]", and you can see that already by the answer by vivek_23.*

Comment: Are values unique? Do you have to find all matches or just see if exists? If you could set index and use `isset` that would be a bit more performant. [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13483219/what-is-faster-in-array-or-isset)

Comment: Yes, values are unique and I can use them as array keys instead of array values if that's the most efficient solution. Anyway, should I sort the array? Does it help with indexing?

Comment: My understanding is `isset` will be O(1) hash search where `in_array` will check every value until it finds a match. isset also has less call overhead. You would not need to sort if setting array index to the name values. See hashtable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is faster: in\_array or isset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13483219/what-is-faster-in-array-or-isset)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I would suggest you to do `sorting` with `binary search` to know if a `value` exists. Time Complexity will be `O(N log N)` for sorting and `O(log N)` to search each individual element, where `N` is the number of elements in the array.
- You could also create an associate array and check with the help of `isset()` to see if the value exists. But, hashing keys would make PHP to internally manage the hash structure consuming a bit of memory since you have `big string arrays`. Also, using `isset($arr['some_key'])` may not be necessarily an `O(1)` operation because of collisions.

Below is my code which uses binary search approach-

```
<?php

function checkIfValueExists($arr,$search_value){

    $low  = 0;
    $high = count($arr) - 1;

    while($low <= $high){
        $mid = $low + intval(($high - $low) / 2);
        $compare_result = strcmp($arr[$mid],$search_value);
        if($compare_result === 0) return true;
        else if($compare_result < 0) $low = $mid + 1;
        else $high = $mid - 1;
    }

    return false;
}
```

The driver code to test above function-

```
<?php 

$arr = array();

$str = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

$values_to_check = array();

for($i=1;$i<=50000;++$i){
    $str_length = rand(1,50);
    $new_str = "";
    while($str_length-- > 0){
        $new_str .= $str[rand(0,25)];
    }

    $arr[]  = $new_str;
    if(rand(0,1) === 1){
        $values_to_check[] = rand(0,1) === 1 ? $new_str . $str[rand(0,25)] : $new_str;
    }
}

// sort the array of strings.

sort($arr);

// test the functionality

foreach($values_to_check as $each_value){
    var_dump(checkIfValueExists($arr,$each_value));
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: +1 Thanks, that's an interesting solution. I'll give you my feedback later, meantime I'm open to new ideas.

Comment: Sure, as you please.