# how to check if there is a key in an array that is in another array?

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to perform actions when there is no key in the table "home" or "reload"

now I have something like this but it does not work

```
$pages = array();
$sql = "SELECT page_name FROM pages";
$result = $con->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$pages[] = $row;    
}   
$page = $_GET['page'];
if( !in_array( $page ,$pages ) )
{
    $_GET['page'] = 'home';
}
```

$pages[] result:

```
    Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [page_name] => Home ) 
[1] => Array ( [page_name] => reload)
```

Comment: you need to  convert your 2d `$pages` array to 1d before checking with `in_array()` or push it like `$pages[] = $row['page_name']; `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling "key" where is "value". Just to be clear and avoid mistakes. You're loading MySQL results as array to an array. To your code works, just change:

```
$result = $con->query ( "SELECT `page_name` FROM `pages`");
$pages = array();
while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc ())
{
  $pages[] = $row["page_name"];
}
if ( ! in_array ( $_GET["page"], $pages))
{
  $_GET["page"] = "home";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `isset()`. See why here : [what is faster: in_array or isset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13483219/what-is-faster-in-array-or-isset).

If you want to use 2d array see this : http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f12fbc6a922fc8583b83534642ef652a4a123010

I prefer Ernani Azevedo answer

Keep coding