# Tuple's GetHashCode hack

Tags: c#, .net, hashcode

Knowing that to obtain hashcode for two objects it is common practice to do XOR of their respective hashcodes I wanted to check how Tuple deals with situation where `Item1 == Item2`. This is what I found in the source code:

```
internal static int CombineHashCodes(int h1, int h2) {
        return (((h1 << 5) + h1) ^ h2);
    }
```

I assume this is to avoid having the same hashcode for all equal objects, because `x ^ x = 0`. Why `h1 << 5` though? Is there a reason why it's specifically `5`? Could it be just `1`? Help me understand this please.

Comment: Lots of ways to write a hashing function that's better than a plain xor and still very fast.  This is Bernstein's hash, aka djb2, minus the seed.  Multiplying by 33 is not arbitrary, covered in [this Q+A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579721/why-are-5381-and-33-so-important-in-the-djb2-algorithm).

Comment: @HansPassant this is the best aswer my question so far, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`((h1 << 5) + h1)` is equivalent to `h1 * 33` and `33` is `3 * 11`. 
Java uses `31` in some hashes since it's prime and `h1 * 31` is `(h1 << 5) - h` which is almost the same, but without additional overflows which might happen in case of sum.

Comment: You may also read some answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299304/why-does-javas-hashcode-in-string-use-31-as-a-multiplier
For example, this one is quiet informative http://stackoverflow.com/a/300111/2577420 (the constants 31, 33, 37, 39, and 41 produce not much collisions)

Comment: `h1 << 5` is actually `h1 * 32`

Comment: @taffer Which means that after adding `h1` again, it becomes `* 33` or after subtracting it becomes `* 31`.

Answer (score 1):

Found something here [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20170923142510/http://www.eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/algorithms/jsw_tut_hashing.aspx)

Read the section on **Shift-Add-XOR hash**

Comment: @MarcL. You realize this Answer is from 5 years ago?

Comment: Yes. The "internet is forever" but individual links are not. That is why [link-only answers are frowned upon](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) (see "Provide Context for Links"). If you can dredge the content up and add some context, I'll be happy to +2.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @HansPassant for pointing me to below question which best explains what I wanted to know:

[Why are 5381 and 33 so important in the djb2 algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579721/why-are-5381-and-33-so-important-in-the-djb2-algorithm)